# Record java with Fraps

Tags: java, swing, crash, jvm

I am writing a little game in Java. I make my graphics using Graphics2D, creating a JPanel, overriding its paint(Graphics g) - method, displaying it in a JFrame by making it its ContentPane.

It works pretty well.

Now i use [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) to test my programs performance. Fraps shows the FPS as usually in one of the corners, no problem. But when i hit the record btton, java crashes. In the NetBeans console it says: `Java Result: -1073740771`

Here is some code:

```
final JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);



    final JPanel myPanel = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            BufferedImage img = world.renderImage(new Point(getWidth(), getHeight()));
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);


        }
    };

    window.setContentPane(myPanel);
    window.setVisible(true);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                myPanel.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

            }
        }
    }.start();
```

What does that mean? How can I avoid this?

Thanks for any awnsers

Erik Brendel

Comment: Could you post (part of) your project? When I start Fraps and a Java project with some graphics, I don't see the FPS values at all. Does your game use OpenGL (since Fraps supports OpenGL and DirectX)?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your problem: when I run Fraps and your project, I don't see any FPS values at all. (I do see them when I run a non-Java game.) The `world.renderImage(new Point(getWidth(), getHeight()))` call is probably the critical part. Can you post (some) of that code as well?

Can you run your application outside of NetBeans (from the command-line or another IDE) to check whether that makes a difference? The "Java Result: [some number]" seems to be related to a crash of the JVM or native code.

For completeness sake: I'm using Java 8 (update 45, 64 bit) on Windows 8.1 (and I prefer IntelliJ IDEA).